# Returning values from a separate function in C++?

Tags: c++

I am doing a programming assignment in my CS class using C++ that is giving me problems. The assignment is to write a program that asks the user to input a Fahrenheit temperature. The program must then output the Celsius equivalent of that temperature and the Celsius equivalents of the next 20 Fahrenheit temperatures. This must all be done using a separate function to complete the conversion calculation as well as a function prototype.

I got everything to work except my Celsius outputs all show a value of 0. I cannot seem to find any errors or figure out what is wrong...Please Help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double Celsius(double temp);

int main() {

double fTemp, cTemp;

cout << "Please input a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ";
cin >> fTemp;

cout << "F Temp" << "       " << "C Temp"<< endl;
cout << "-------------------" << endl;

for(int count=1; count<= 20; count++){

    cTemp = Celsius(fTemp);

    cout << setw(6) << fTemp << setw(12) << cTemp<< endl;

    fTemp++;

}


return 0;
}

//*************Celsius Function****************//

double Celsius(double temp){

double newC;
newC = (temp-32) * (5/9);
return newC;

}
//************************************************
```

Comment: Would you be surprising to learn that 5 divided by 9 is 0? That's what happens when you use integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(5/9)` is integer-integer division. You might've as well typed `0` there. Replace it with (`5.0/9.0`) and it should be fine.

Comment: That was a dumb mistake on my part. Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

One could simply try (5.0/9.0) or use a type cast by doing something like

```
double Celsius(double temp){
  double newC;
  newC = (temp-32) * (float)5/9;
  return newC;
}
```

Thereby, you will not be getting a straight 0 in your outputs.

Comment: `(float)(5/9)` is `0`. You are doing integer division first and then cast the result to float.

Comment: sorry i meant typecasting the numerator first so that'd be
`(float)5/9`
Thanks for pointing out